# Error on AWS Lambda with moviepy and numpy

Tags: python, numpy, aws-lambda, python-3.7, moviepy

I've been trying to package my python app for lambda that uses moviepy but I keep getting this error:

```
Original error was: No module named 'numpy.core._multiarray_umath'
```

I've been trying different ways to package my python 3.7 app for lambda but I haven't figured anything out. Is there some way to resolve this or maybe some other python library that can concatenate and resize videos that doesn't use numpy?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From error as per in question lambda you are executing is not having module of numpy and moviepy. you have forget to add modules in lambda. add dependency first and run it will work.

you can also zip you modles and upload it to lambda from console.

Answer (score 0):

The issue and resolution are described [here](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/build-python-lambda-deployment-package/):

> "ModuleNotFoundError" and "Module cannot be loaded" are common errors for Lambda functions in Python. These errors are usually due to incorrect folder structure or file permissions with the deployment package .zip file.

For additional packages, have you looked at [moviepy](http://zulko.github.io/moviepy/index.html). Mind you, changing package doesn't resolve your issue. You need to include the package modules in the lambda zip by following the instructions above.

Comment: Interesting I explicitly packaged all the dependencies (including moviepy) but I'll see about the other issues.